# How do attackers achieve to compromise a CA?

Tags: authentication, certificates, public-key-infrastructure

There are several posts out there stating that some CAs have been compromised and had given away fraudulent certificates.

Given the fact that keys are stored on a HSM and only the public key is available to others, how can an attacker obtain CA private key? Is there any way an attacker could issue a certificate to an entity, other than obtaining CA private key?

Comment: Usually people undermine CA procedures to get certs signed that shouldn't have been signed. Breaking a (high-priced and certified) HSM such that the private key can be extracted is _extremely rare_ even in lab conditions.

Comment: How can one obtain a cert that shouldnt be signed? From what I know the csr should be signed by the ca, thus the attacker should have access to the ca itself. That is somehow unreachable, though.

Comment: In the case of the DigiNotar the attacker simply compromised the domain admin password, giving them access to an account with permission to issue certificates. No need to compromise the CA's private key.

Comment: @puzzlepalace shouldn't that service be authenticated by a cert as well?

Comment: Well a lot of things *should* be done in theory, but unfortunately in practice they sometimes don't happen. E.g. the domain admin password probably *shouldn't* have been `Pr0d@dm1n` either.

Comment: CA certs can chain - they can issue another CA certificate. If you get one of those fraudulently, you've effectively compromised the CA

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to get access to the CA's private key in order to get a certificate issued. The CA probably does not have access to the private key either, especially if it was created inside the smartcard or HSM itself.

Instead fraudulent certificates gets issued by the CA because

- **The attacker makes the CA believe that he is the owner of the domain:**
  This can be done because of the automatic validation of domain ownership in DV certificates. This validation is usually done by implementing some challenge-response methods using special e-mail accounts, special path of the webserver or DNS records in the owners domain. Compromise is thus possible if the attacker gets access to specific mail accounts in the domain
  like in the [case of
  live.fi](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/bogus-ssl-certificate-for-windows-live-could-allow-man-in-the-middle-hacks/).
  It can also be done by making the CA believe in a different contact
  email for the domain like in case of [Comodo OCR
  problems](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/10/21/comodoh_researchers_exploit_image_recognition_bug_to_steal_certs/).
  DV validation can also be tricked if the attacker manages to
  compromise the original site to attack webserver path validation or the sites DNS to attack DNS record validation.
- **Third parties violate usage constraints for CA's issued sub-CA:**
  This happened for example in the cases of a [french sub-CA which was used for SSL interception](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/12/10/french_gov_dodgy_ssl_cert_reprimand/) and issued certificates (among others) for google.com.
- **Bugs in the CA processes:**
  like in case of [TURKTRUST](https://security.googleblog.com/2013/01/enhancing-digital-certificate-security.html) which accidentally issued sub-CA certificates instead of normal certificates, which then could be used to issue new certificates for arbitrary domains.
- **Compromise of the CA itself:**
  This happened in case of [DigiNotar](https://threatpost.com/final-report-diginotar-hack-shows-total-compromise-ca-servers-103112/77170/) where the attacker managed to get deep access into the infrastructure of the CA. The [final report (PDF)](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/binaries/rijksoverheid/documenten/rapporten/2012/08/13/black-tulip-update/black-tulip-update.pdf) about this attack points out that it looks like where DigiNotar where having the private key in the smartcards active for automatic transactions, i.e. not every smartcard transaction would have to be explicitly authorized. This probably allowed the attacker to sign it's own certificates without having physical access to the system and without having the private key.